# Return id after sql insert java

Tags: java, sql

After inserting data into my database the database automatically generates and ID which I would like to get returned to me. But I have no idea how...

```
public Integer addPerson(person p) throws DBException {
    try (Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();) {
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                "insert into klant(name, date) values (?,?)");) {
            stmt.setString(1, p.getName());
            stmt.setObject(2, Date.valueOf(p.getDate()));
            stmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            throw new DBException(s);
        }

    } catch (SQLException s) {
        throw new DBException(s);
    }
    return id_generated_by_db;
}
```

Comment: You could use the "RETURNING " clause (if you are using PostgreSQL)

Comment: Use another query `"SELECT id FROM klant WHERE name=" + p.getName()  + " AND date=" + Date.valueOf(p.getDate())`

Comment: @Blobonat That's more of an emergency solution... You never know two people have the same name and are born on the same date (unlikely but plausible)

Comment: @JirneVanCamp You could order it by the id and only take the last entry, but yes it is not a very nice solution.

Comment: There's no need to argue when JDBC has a standard solution.

Comment: This DBMS specific (e.g. MS SQL : @@identity)